# For two integer user inputs, how to detect that a string has been passed on the very first input?

Tags: java, string, input, try-catch, numberformatexception

This is my code. A program to check for prime numbers between user inputs, 'start' and 'stop'.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter start: ");
            String start = sc.nextLine();
            if(start.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter stop: ");
            String stop = sc.nextLine();
            if(stop.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            {
                break;
            }
            try
            {
                int s1 = Integer.parseInt(start);
                try
                {
                    int s2 = Integer.parseInt(stop);
                    for(int i = s1; i<=s2;i++)
                    {
                        if(p1.isPrime(i))
                        {
                            System.out.print(i+" ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException er)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                }
            }
            catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException er1)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

When taking start input, if I enter any string, I want the code to instantly detect NumberFormatException and ask for the same input again.

What happens instead, is that, it takes both inputs, whether string and integer, and only then evaluates whether it's a string.

I don't use `sc.nextLine()` because I want the stop functionality. I want the program to stop execution if I input "stop" anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int start = -1;
        int stop = -1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (start == -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter start: ");
                if (sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    start = sc.nextInt();
                } else if (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) break;
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (stop == -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter stop: ");
                if (sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    stop = sc.nextInt();
                } else if (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) break;
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
            {
                 // Prime number method call here
                System.out.print(i + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
            start = stop = -1;
        }
    }
```